# What are examples of non-trivial POVM measurements?

Tags: measurement, textbook-and-exercises, povm

We know that generalized (POVM) measurement is defined by matrices $M_i$ which are

- Positive semidefinite
- Add up to a unit matrix, $\sum_i M_i = \mathbb{I}$

and the probability of obtaining outcome $i$ on state $\rho$ is

- $p_i = Tr(\rho M_i)$

I can easily construct POVM example on a qubit by choosing

- $M_0 = |\Psi\rangle\langle\Psi|$
- $M_1 = \mathbb{I}- |\Psi\rangle\langle\Psi|$

But this is simply a projective measurement (on state $\Psi$).

How to construct a non-trivial (non-projective) POVM measurement example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a few examples

### POVMs with two components

These are POVMs involving only two matrices $M_1,M_2\ge0$ with $M_1+M_2=I$.
This implies that they are mutually diagonalisable, as discussed *e.g.* [in this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3457408/173147). Using their (mutual) eigenvectors as basis, we can therefore always write them as

$$\newcommand{\on}[1]{{\operatorname{#1}}} M_1 = \on{diag}(s_1,..., s_N),
\qquad M_2 = \on{diag}(1-s_1,...,1-s_N),$$
where $N$ is the dimension of the underlying space and $s_i\in[0,1]$.
Note that $M_i$ are not, in general, projections.

For a concrete example, consider
$M_1 = M_2 = \on{diag}(1/2,1/2). %\begin{pmatrix}1/2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1/2\end{pmatrix}.$
Of course, this represents a completely useless measurement, as $\on{Tr}(\rho M_i)=1/2$ for all $\rho$.

### POVMs that are sum of projectors

Suppose $N=3$, $\newcommand{\bs}[1]{\boldsymbol{#1}}\newcommand{\PP}{\mathbb P}\newcommand{\ketbra}[1]{\lvert #1\rangle\!\langle #1\rvert}$ and consider $M_1=\ketbra1+\ketbra2$ and $M_2=\ketbra3$. This is a POVM that's also not sum of trace-1 projectors.

You can also show that, if $N=2$, the only POVMs that are sum of projectors have the form $\{\PP(\bs u),\PP(-\bs u)\}$, where $\PP(\bs u)\equiv \frac12 (I+\bs u\cdot\bs \sigma)$ projects onto the $+1$ eigenspace of $\bs u\cdot\bs \sigma\equiv\sum_k u_k \sigma_k$, with $\sigma_k$ the Pauli matrices and $u\in\mathbb R^3$ with $\|\bs u\|=1$.
This can be seen from the above observation about diagonalisability. Another proof is found around page 19 of these notes by Nicholas Wheeler ([Link to pdf](https://www.reed.edu/physics/faculty/wheeler/documents/Quantum%20Mechanics/Miscellaneous%20Essays/Generalized%20Quantum%20Measurement/Generalized%20Quantum%20Measurements.pdf)).

Still considering the qubit case $N=2$, we can more generally take a set of $n$ vectors $\mathbf a_i$ such that $\sum_i \mathbf a_i=0$ and $\|\mathbf a_i\|\le1$, and then
$$\sum_i \frac{2}{n}\PP(\mathbf a_i) = I,$$
so that $\big\{\frac{2}{n}\PP(\mathbf a_i)\big\}_{i=1}^n$ is an $n$-element qubit POVM. This is also shown in Wheeler's notes linked above.

A question related to this is [*Are three POVM measurements on a single qubit physically realizable?*](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/8814/55).

### State discrimination

Another common scenario is unambiguous state discrimination. Given two pure states $\newcommand{\ket}[1]{\lvert #1\rangle}\ket\psi,\ket\varphi$, the optimal POVM to distinguish between them is
$$M_1 = \frac{1}{1+\lvert\langle\varphi|\psi\rangle\rvert}\ketbra{\varphi^\perp},
\quad
M_2 = \frac{1}{1+\lvert\langle\varphi|\psi\rangle\rvert}\ketbra{\psi^\perp},
\quad
M_3 = I - M_1 - M_2.
$$

On the other hand, the POVM that optimally distinguishes between two states, uses $M_1=\sum_{i: \lambda_i>0}\mathbb{P}(|\lambda_i\rangle)$,  $M_2=\sum_{i: \lambda_i<0}\mathbb{P}(|\lambda_i\rangle)$, where $|\lambda_i\rangle$ is the eigenstate with eigenvalue $\lambda_i$ of $\mathbb{P}(|\psi\rangle)-\mathbb{P}(|\phi\rangle)$, where $|\psi\rangle,|\phi\rangle$ are the states we are trying to discriminate.
This is also discussed in [*What is the Helstrom measurement?*](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/4172/55).

For example, to optimally discriminate between $|0\rangle$ and $|+\rangle$, we get
$$M_1 = \frac1{2(2-\sqrt2)}\mathbb{P}((-1+\sqrt2)|0\rangle+|1\rangle)
= \frac1{2(2-\sqrt2)} \begin{pmatrix}3-2\sqrt2 & \sqrt2-1\\\sqrt2-1&1\end{pmatrix}, \\
M_2 = \frac1{2(2+\sqrt2)}\mathbb{P}((-1-\sqrt2)|0\rangle+|1\rangle)
= \frac1{2(2+\sqrt2)} \begin{pmatrix}3+2\sqrt2 & -\sqrt2-1\\-\sqrt2-1&1\end{pmatrix}.
$$

### Example without any specific structure

A generic example with $N=3$, given [in this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3660111/173147), is
$$
M_1 =\frac{1}{9}
  \begin{pmatrix}
    3 & 2 & -1\\
    2 & 3 & -1\\
    -1 & -1 & 3\\
  \end{pmatrix},
\quad
M_2 =\frac{1}{9}
  \begin{pmatrix}
    3 & -1 & 2\\
    -1 & 3 & -1\\
    2 & -1 & 3\\
  \end{pmatrix},
\quad
M_3 =\frac{1}{9}
  \begin{pmatrix}
    3 & -1 & -1\\
    -1 & 3 & 2\\
    -1 & 2 & 3\\
  \end{pmatrix}.
$$

Comment: also related is: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/17349/55