# Random quantum circuits and general efficient POVM measurement

Tags: quantum-circuit, quantum-advantage, probability, random-quantum-circuit, haar-distribution

Let's consider a random quantum circuit $C$, applied to the $n$ qubit initial state $|0^{n}\rangle$, producing the state $|\psi\rangle$.

Consider a general efficiently implementable $m$-outcome POVM measurement $\{M_i : i = 0, 1, \ldots, m-1\}$. Let

\begin{equation}
p_i = \text{Tr}\big(M_i |\psi\rangle \langle \psi|\big).
\end{equation}

Is anything known, in general, about

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[p_i] ~~\text{and}~~\mathbb{E}[p_i^{2}]
\end{equation}
where the expectation is taken over the choices of the random circuit?

I am especially interested in the case when the POVM elements $M_i$ describe an entangled multi-qubit measurement (which is efficiently implementable).

---

Note that for the special case of when the POVM corresponds to an $2^{n}$-outcome standard basis measurement, we know that
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[p_i] = \frac{1}{2^{n}}, ~~~ \mathbb{E}[p_i^{2}] = \frac{2}{2^{n}(2^{n} + 1)}.
\end{equation}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the absence of additional assumptions, $\mathbb{E}[p_i]$ can be any real number in $[0, 1]$. For example, let $a\in[0,1]$ and define the POVM as $M_0=aI$ and $M_1=(1-a)I$. Then

$$
\mathbb{E}[p_0] = \int \mathrm{tr}\left(aI|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|\right)d\psi  = a \int \langle\psi|\psi\rangle d\psi = a
$$

assuming the Haar measure is normalized. Similarly, $\mathbb{E}[p_1]=1-a$.

In the special case of the $2^n$-outcome measurement in the computational basis of all qubits, the fact that the respective POVM elements are orthogonal projectors is essential to obtaining $\mathbb{E}[p_i]=2^{-n}$.

---

For any candidate property of general POVMs, it pays to consider a number of simple special cases such as orthogonal projectors (as you did in your question), multiples of identity (as I did in my answer) and others such as SIC-POVMs. See also [this question](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/13426/10480) for additional inspiration.

Comment: One question out of curiosity, if we put one additional assumption --- that the POVMs are orthogonal projectors (not necessarily standard basis projectors but arbitrary ones) --- can we then say anything extra about the first and second moments? Perhaps, something like if it is an $m$ outcome POVM, then the first moment is ~ 1/m?

Comment: One observation: if the POVMs are orthogonal projectors and also unentangled across qubits, it follows directly from the translational invariance of the Haar measure that the second moment is the same. I am thinking about the entangled measurement case (let's say, for example, a Bell basis measurement on pairs of qubits): I have a hunch that the second moment should still be something like the unentangled case, but  I could not show it.

Answer (score 0):

Using the formula mentioned in this [question](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/28615/show-that-averaging-over-uniformly-random-unitaries-mathbbeuxu-dagger). We have
$$\mathbb{E} [p_i]=\mathbb{E} \left[ \mathrm{Tr(}M_i|\psi \rangle \langle \psi |) \right] 
\\
=\mathrm{Tr(}M_i\int_{\mathbf{U}(d)}{d}\mu (U)U|0^n\rangle \langle 0^n|U^{\dagger})
\\
=\mathrm{Tr(}\int_{\mathbf{U}(d)}{d}\mu (U)U^{\dagger}M_iU|0^n\rangle \langle 0^n|)
\\
=Tr\left( \frac{Tr\left( M_i \right)}{2^n}|0^n\rangle \langle 0^n| \right) 
\\
=\frac{Tr\left( M_i \right)}{2^n}$$